# Open/Close zozo accordion tabs using custom button

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

I am using ZOZO accordion jquery plugin to add a accordion in my web form.
The plugin allows me to divide my web form in various sections. Each section wrapped in a ZOZO tab. The first tab is opened by default using the jquery code below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $("#demo-accordion").zozoAccordion({
    theme: "silver",
    active: 0,
    sectionSpacing: 4
  });
});
```

I want to use a custom button that would simply close existing tab and open another tab.
I am using this code to do that

```
$("#start-ff").on("click", function(){
  $("#demo-accordion").zozoAccordion({
    active: 1
  });
});
```

It isn't working though. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't working"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are doing on button click is re-creating the accoridion.

if you are looking to select one of your accordion then check out the following code.

`$("#demo-accordion").data("zozoAccordion").select(1); //where 1 is the index of accordian you want to select`

for more reference look up Docs at 
http://docs.zozoui.com/accordion/

look in the methods section, you will find lots of use full functions in it.